# Работа c RDP Возвращаем рабочий стол на экран

Tags: rdp

Есть системник, на нем отображаются фото сотрудников проходящих через турникет.
К нему подключатся по RDP, производят настройки.
Отключаются от RDP сессии и экран остается в режиме выбора пользователя.
Как можно по завершению RDP сессии вернуть рабочий экран без выбора пользователя?
Можно использовать только RDP.

Comment: Подозреваю, что никак. Из области костылей - перезагрузка с автовходом. Хотя какой-то странный и сомнительный вариант.

Comment: возможно ответ здесь: https://superuser.com/questions/962633/windows-10-auto-login-after-connecting-via-rdp-mstsc